# iOS: Memory Management in UIScrollView with many UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

i've got a question regarding a UIScrollView with paging enabled that contains many UIView, each managed by an own UIViewController.

Right now there are about 20 to 30 UIViewControllers that COULD be contained in the UIScrollView. It's a catalog app on the iPad, and I started preloading all the views at the beginning, but with the amount of UIViewControllers getting bigger and bigger, that is not an option any more.

I'm looking for the perfect solution in terms of memory usage. It's no problem to reload the UIViewControllers when the ContentOffset of the ScrollView reaches a specific controller. And I think to nil the UIViewControllers when the ContentOffset tells me that the UIViewControllers is not needed any more isn't that hard as well.

What is the correct way to handle this? Is it enough to alloc the UIViewControllers when needed, putting them into a NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray and nil them when they are not needed any more? A little bit of help from someone already having done something similar would be great!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your design is wrong. You should not 'put' UIViewControllers into a scrollView.

Comment: I'm not putting UIViewControllers into a UIScrollView, i'm putting the UIViewControllers' UIView into the UIScrollView.

Comment: Of course, that is what I mean, and you should not do it. Try to make it so you have only 1 view controller which controls the views stored into the scrollView.

Comment: But these views are complicated, each of them gets data loaded via CoreData, handles the data seperately, has many observing methods. Please tell me your decision when to use a UIViewController and when to only create a UIView and putting it into a UIScrollView.

Comment: Usually the rule of thumb is to have a view controller managing its entire screen. You can still handle your data separately and handle observing methods into 1 view controller. Use inheritance and polymorphism. Anyhow, regardless of the design, I have an idea how to solve your problem and will include it in an answer soon.

Comment: @pe60t0 While your "one view controller per screen" was traditionally the axiom we all lived by, with the introduction of custom container view controllers, it is now not uncommon to have multiple controllers for a given screen. As long as chritaso is doing the [necessary calls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) to `addChildViewController`, `didMoveToParentViewController`, etc., then he should be fine.

Comment: Of course, but if he is targeting iOS < 5.0 , this is not possible

Comment: @chritaso In answer to your question, I think the right model is one designed like `UITableView` and `UIContainerView`, where you have a notion of cells that are reused as you scroll down the table or container view. I generally make sure that I keep the "previous" and the "next" cells around (to make it really responsive to gestures), but the idea is the same.

Comment: @Rob that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to dynamically load the UIViewControllers and put their views into the scrollview. Now what I'm asking for is how to handle UIViewControllers, how to dealloc them when no longer needed. Is it enough to say "viewController = nil", should I call removeFromSuperview?

Comment: @pe60t0 I'm targeting iOS >= 5.1

Comment: @chritaso Then you just set yourself up as a `UIScrollViewDelegate`, respond to `scrollViewDidScroll`, and from that you can release the views (and their controllers) that you don't need and load any ones that you do. Just make sure to do the necessary custom containment calls (which I hope you were doing already, anyway).

Comment: @chritaso If you search for "`UIScrollView` infinite scroll" or "`UIScrollView` infinite paging" you'll probably find all sorts of useful references, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444869/1271826

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there are some good infinite scrolling classes out there, but if you were going to "roll your own", here is a minimalist bit of code that demonstrates the process of infinite scrolling, keeping the current, previous, and next pages in memory, but letting go of anything else. This assumes that:

- you're doing horizontal scrolling and have turned on paging;
- that you're using view controllers for the child views;
- your child view controller class has a `page` property to keep track of what page it's for; and
- you've made your view controller the delegate for your scroll view

Thus, it might look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // my underlying model is just an array of strings, which I'll show on my child
    // view; your model will be more elaborate, but I just want to illustrate the concept

    self.objects = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9"];

    // set the `contentSize` for the scrollview

    CGRect content = self.view.bounds;
    content.size.width *= [self.objects count]; // make it wide enough to hold everything
    self.scrollView.contentSize = content.size;

    // set our current page and load the first pages (the first and the next pages)

    self.currentPage = 0;
    [self addChildPage:0 toScrollView:self.scrollView];
    [self addChildPage:1 toScrollView:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)addChildPage:(NSInteger)page toScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // create the child controller

    ChildViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"child"];

    // set whatever properties you need to in order for it to present its information correctly

    controller.text = self.objects[page];
    controller.page = page;

    // now do the stuff to add it to the right place in the scrollview

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [self addChildViewController:controller];        // containment call for adding child view controller
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self]; // containment call when done adding child
}

- (ChildViewController *)childControllerForPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    for (ChildViewController *controller in self.childViewControllers)
    {
        if (controller.page == page)
            return controller;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)addChildIfNecessary:(NSInteger)page toScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (page < 0 || page >= [self.objects count])
        return;

    ChildViewController *controller = [self childControllerForPage:page];

    if (controller == nil)
        [self addChildPage:page toScrollView:scrollView];
}

- (void)removeChildController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [controller willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // containment call before removing child
    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [controller removeFromParentViewController];      // containment call to remove child
}

- (void)updateChildrenViewsForPage:(NSInteger)page forScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (page == self.currentPage)
        return;

    // add child pages as necessary

    [self addChildIfNecessary:page     toScrollView:scrollView];
    [self addChildIfNecessary:(page-1) toScrollView:scrollView];
    [self addChildIfNecessary:(page+1) toScrollView:scrollView];

    // find any pages that need removing

    NSMutableArray *pagesToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (ChildViewController *controller in self.childViewControllers)
    {
        if (controller.page < (page - 1) ||
            controller.page > (page + 1))
        {
            [pagesToRemove addObject:controller];
        }
    }

    // remove them if they need removing

    for (UIViewController *controller in pagesToRemove)
    {
        [self removeChildController:controller];
    }

    // update our "current page" index

    self.currentPage = page;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width + 0.5;

    [self updateChildrenViewsForPage:page forScrollView:scrollView];
}
```

This demonstrates the appropriate custom container calls and the handling of the scroll events. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Thats a really detailed answer that will help me a lot!

Comment: The only problem I have now is that the controllers are not deallocated correctly. I don't know why, but the dealloc method of each controller gets called, I nil every view I do an alloc for, nonetheless there is more and more memory allocated. Could this be ank IBOutlet problem...?

Comment: @chritaso How have you determined this? Is the `Leaks` tool showing you leaks? (If so, you can look at the call tree and identify precisely what is being leaked, which is the first step in resolving the leak.) Or are you looking at the `Allocations` tool? Some people mistakenly look at "Overall bytes" (which includes things that have been released), but you should look at "Live Bytes".

Comment: @chritaso Also, am I correct in assuming you're using ARC? If not, it's incredibly easy to leak. Also, have you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu)?

Comment: I'm using the Allocations tool, and the problem is that at the beginning there is only the memory allocated that is needed for the controller, but after scrolling 2 or 3 times, the memory usage gets up continuously without stopping. There are no memory Leaks, at least there are none displayed. And yes, I'm using ARC. Analyzer says that all is fine. And these are the living bytes, not the overall. Could it have something to do with UIViews that get deallocated, but Animations that are still living?

Comment: @chritaso Are you using anything that might be caching data (such as network operations, web views, `imageNamed` method of `UIImage`, etc.)? Also, is the increase in Live Bytes significant (megabytes)? Also, have you confirmed that you infinite scrolling is removing the old views? For example, when testing, I put `NSLog` in my `dealloc` methods for my view controllers to make sure they're getting released like I wanted. It's nice to know precisely when things are deallocated sometimes.

Comment: @chritaso Also, if you're seeing observable bump in the allocation, you can use the allocations tool to select part of your timeline and see what was allocated during that period; very useful in diagnosing what's being allocated when). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15212695/1271826 for example.

Comment: Bottom line, minor increases in live bytes is customary. Or increases if you use `imageNamed` or network operations that might cache are also customary. The one type of "leak" that is annoying and not caught by Instruments is the "I added a view but neglected to remove it" bug. So, just put log statements in your `dealloc` methods and hopefully identify anything that's allocated and not released.

Comment: I'm using the imageNamed method at some points. I also have WebViews, but they only load local HTML because of formatting reasons. I already use a NSLog in every dealloc method that is called in every controller, and they get called. In the dealloc method, I nil every view. Thanks to your instructions how to use the Allocations tool more efficient, I found out that the problem is that I use a KenBurns view from another developer, and he uses a UIView animateWithDuration method. After the animation is finished, the method calls itself again.

Comment: So I nilled the view, but I think the animateWithDuration block now was a continuous loop. Same with NSTimer, when I nil a view that uses a timer, the NSLog says that the timer is still working, unless i nilled everything. Do I have to explicitely call the invalidate method to kill the timer? And why is it still called when I nil the view and the view should be "dead"? Thanks so much for your help Rob.

Comment: @chritaso let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27102/discussion-between-rob-and-chritaso)